# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am using pandas to read csv on my machine then I create a pyspark dataframe from pandas dataframe.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

I updated my pandas from version `1.3.0` to `2.0`

Now, I am getting this error:

[image]

---

[image]

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Seems like this is similar to this issue here. Maybe could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926636/databricks-issue-while-creating-spark-data-frame-from-pandas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found an answer on github: https://github.com/YosefLab/Compass/issues/92

It is an issue going on.

`iteritems` is removed from `pandas 2.0`

For now I need to downgrade pandas back to version `1.5.3`

---

**Edit:**

Other workarounds may be

Use the latest Spark (3.4.1)

https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

---

### For pandas >=2.0

You can also assign `DataFrame.items` to `DataFrame.iteritems`

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html?highlight=items#pandas.DataFrame.items

Comment: It may require some additional workaround, but [DataFrame.items](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html?highlight=items#pandas.DataFrame.items) seems to perform what you need it to