# ImportError: cannot import name 'KoalasFrame' from 'databricks.koalas'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, spark-koalas

I got below warning and error

```
from databricks.koalas import KoalasFrame

WARNING:root:Found pyspark version "3.5.0" installed. The pyspark version 3.2 and above has a built-in "pandas APIs on Spark" module ported from Koalas. Try `import pyspark.pandas as ps` instead. 
WARNING:root:'PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE' environment variable was not set. It is required to set this environment variable to '1' in both driver and executor sides if you use pyarrow>=2.0.0. Koalas will set it for you but it does not work if there is a Spark context already launched.


ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
cnrl\users\yongnual\Data\Spyder_workplace\DTS_dashboard\pandas2_high_performance_testing.ipynb Cell 18 line 1
----> 1 from databricks.koalas import KoalasFrame

ImportError: cannot import name 'KoalasFrame' from 'databricks.koalas' (c:\Anaconda\envs\dash2\lib\site-packages\databricks\koalas\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no module `KoalasFrame` in `databricks.koalas`**

```
pip install databricks
pip install koalas
pip install pyspark

from databricks.koalas import KoalasFrame

#Error
ImportError: cannot import name 'KoalasFrame' from 'databricks.koalas'
```

You can check the methods available in `databricks.koalas` by:

```
dir(databricks.koalas)

['DataFrame',
 'Index',
 'LooseVersion',
 'MultiIndex',
 'NamedAgg',
 'Series',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '__warningregistry__',
 '_auto_patch',
 'assert_pyspark_version',
 'broadcast',
 'concat',
 'from_pandas',
 'get_dummies',
 'get_option',
 'groupby',
 'isna',
 'isnull',
 'melt',
 'merge',
 'namespace',
 'notna',
 'notnull',
 'option_context',
 'options',
 'os',
 'pandas_wraps',
 'pyarrow',
 'pyspark',
 'range',
 'read_clipboard',
 'read_csv',
 'read_delta',
 'read_excel',
 'read_html',
 'read_json',
 'read_parquet',
 'read_spark_io',
 'read_sql',
 'read_sql_query',
 'read_sql_table',
 'read_table',
 'reset_option',
 'set_option',
 'sql',
 'to_datetime',
 'to_numeric']
```

---

I assume that you mean:

```
from databricks.koalas import DataFrame
```

https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.html

Comment: thanks, I tried and when I convert pandas's dataframe into Koalas, it has an error of DataFrame object has no atrributed 'iteritems.  The way I did is:  kdf=DataFrame(df)

Comment: @roudan you can try `import pandas as pd...
pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items` before using `kdf=DataFrame(df)`

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76404811/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and got another error:  AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.

Comment: you're welcome... What is your numpy version?

Comment: my numpy version is 1.25.2

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893742/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-bool

Comment: You're welcome bro

Answer (score 1):

Koalas package is deprecated as this functionality is merged into Apache Spark as [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html).  Follow the steps outlined in the Pandas API on Spark [user guides](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html). Instead of importing `databricks.koalas` you need to import `pyspark.pandas`:

```py
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

that has it's own `DataFrame` class.

Comment: thanks, I tried and when I convert pandas's dataframe into Apache Spark DataFrame, it has an error of PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.  The way I did is:  kdf=ps.DataFrame(df)

Comment: I think it's more to the PySpark installation, like, wrong Java version is used, or incorrectly configured