# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems' after Dataframe converted to pandas

Tags: python, databricks

```py
df= (df_driver
.filter(f.col("userCount").isNotNull())
.withColumn('userCount', add_columns(column, "userCount").cast("integer"))
.withColumn("usedBy", f.lit(MODIFIED_BY))
.withColumn("dateUsed", f.lit(date_today).cast("timestamp"))
.drop("userName2", "userName")
)

#Converting to Pandas Dataframe
df_to_pd= df.toPandas()
```

However, I got this error:

UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' is set to true.

Here's the datatype of df:

```
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
date:date
userId:string
userTypeId:string
userCount:integer
userDeviceId:string
userTypeCategory:string
usedOn:timestamp
versionNumber:integer
usedBy:string
dateUsed:timestamp
```

I am using databricks runtime version 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)

Any answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926636/databricks-issue-while-creating-spark-data-frame-from-pandas) link answer your question.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Databricks: Issue while creating spark data frame from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926636/databricks-issue-while-creating-spark-data-frame-from-pandas)

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh first, it worked after i downgraded the pandas version into 1.5.3 however when I tried to run it again, Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported. Pass e.g. 'datetime64[ns]' instead. That error I got.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Pandas version? After Pandas 2.0, `.iteritems` function is removed. If you want to keep the original code you can add this before your code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items
```

Comment: i try it also but the error still persists.

Comment: I have disabled it. Still throws the same error