# ArrowInvalid Exception converting numpy array of single string element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyarrow

ArrowInvalid Exception is raised when converting numpy array of single string element, but works as expected with more than 1 element.

Any clue why that is, and how fix (besides the cast workaround below)?

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926636/databricks-issue-while-creating-spark-data-frame-from-pandas
pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items
import numpy as np

import findspark
findspark.init('')
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import types as T
import pyarrow

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf().setAll(list())).getOrCreate()
pdf = pd.DataFrame([''], columns=['c1'])

# fails with 1 element:
pdf['c1'].iloc[0] = np.array(['x'])

# works with 2 elements:
# pdf['c1'].iloc[0] = np.array(['x', 'y'])
# also works if casted to list:
# pdf['c1'].iloc[0] = list(np.array(['x']))

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf, T.StructType([T.StructField('c1', T.ArrayType(T.StringType(), True))]))
df.show()
```

Expected result:

```
+---+
| c1|
+---+
|[x]|
+---+
```

Actual result:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Can only convert 1-dimensional array values
```

Versions:

```
python.version: 3.9.18
pd.__version__: 2.1.1
np.__version__: 1.26.0
pyarrow.__version__: 11.0.0
spark.version: 3.2.3
```

Comment: Something weir is happening during the assignment. `np.array(['x']).shape` is `(1,)`. But after calling `pdf['c1'].iloc[0] = np.array(['x'])`, `pdf['c1'].iloc[0].shape` becomes `()`. That's what later causes arrow to complain. I think it has to do with the internals of pandas. I'd recommend finding another way to set this columns value.